# Deseq2 package: DESeqDataSetFromHTSeqCount not found

Tags: r, error-handling, installation, rcpp, seq

I have installed DESeq 2 and it gives this error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DESeq2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
```

I have then tried to install RCPP but it gives the following error message:

```
1 error generated.
make: *** [api.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have updated everything I could, R and R studio as well as my mac but the error persists.

Therefore when I try to run the following function of DESeq2 I can't run it and it gives me the following error which I guess is due to not having Rcpp:

```
 dds <- DESeqDataSetFromHTSeqCount(sampleTable = sampleTable,
+                                   directory = getwd(),
+                                   design= ~ replicate +  condition )
Error in DESeqDataSetFromHTSeqCount(sampleTable = sampleTable, directory = getwd(),  : 
  could not find function "DESeqDataSetFromHTSeqCount"
```

Any help or solution on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!!

Alerie

Comment: did you install xcode? changes are you need that to have Rcpp installed

Comment: I will second @StupidWolf 's comment. Moreover, something that would be helpful is if you [edit] your question to include some more info. Specifically, there should be more output after you enter the command `install.packages("Rcpp")` but before `1 error generated.`. Having that other output will help others help you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  We need to know more details:  What OS?  What version?  What type of installation (source or binary)?  What compiler?   Your question is almost unanswerable as posted.